# Setter for elements inside ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, contentpresenter

I have a `ControlTemplate` like this :

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" Color="Black" ShadowDepth="0"
                                      Opacity="0.5" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" Color="Black" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="1" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

When IsMouseOver property changes to True, I want all the images inside the `contentPresenter` to have the DropShadowEffect, not the button itself.
I tried changing the setter property to `Image.Effect` but it doesn't work.
How can I do it?

This is how my button looks like when Mouse is over:  [image]
And this is how it looks when it is not: [image]
As you can see, both the Image and TextBlock is getting dropshadow effect. But I want only the Image to get it.

Comment: I misunderstood your problem, ignore my previous comments. What doesn't work? Can you attach a screenshot to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @Sinatr I have edited the question and added some screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the style recommended by Sinatr and put it in the `ControlTemplate.Resources` section of your button's control template. Here's an example that worked for me. It also handles the `IsPressed` event, during which I assume you want adjust the drop shadow effect for just the image:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BtnTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" Color="Black" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="0.5"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" Color="Black" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="1" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to define `Button` template, rather create an `Image` style

```
<Style x:Key="style"
       TargetType="Image">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"
                     Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20"
                                          Color="Black"
                                          ShadowDepth="0"
                                          Opacity="0.5" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger.Setters>
        </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
```

and apply it to each image you show inside button

```
<Button>
...
    <Image Style="{StaticResource style}" ... />
...
</Button>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no way to do it using the ControlTemplate? (btw, the control template is needed because I want to override the button's template and provide my own.)

Comment: I provide you with one solution of the problem. Maybe there are other possibilities, but this is what I would do. If there would be many buttons like you show, then I'd probably end up with custom control (to be able at least to assign different images to the button's image).