# ControlTemplate set foreground of ContentPresenter containing UserControl with trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I am creating a ControlTemplate for a TabItem and I am trying to set the foreground color of the usercontrol contained in the ContentPresenter used in the template. I can not set it on the ContentPresenter itself because a ContentPresenter does not have the Foreground Property.

The reason why I want to set it on the ContentPresenter (or the user control in the ContentPresenter), and not on the TabItem itself is because changing the TabItem Foreground color causes the object in the TabItem's Content Property to also inherit the foreground color, and not just the header, which is not intended. Basically I only wan't to change the TabItems Header object Foreground color, which is represented by the Content Presenter.

This is what my code looks like:

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                <Grid x:Name="Root">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      ContentSource="Header"
                                      Margin="10 20" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex"
                                Value="100" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Presenter"
                                Property="UserControl.Foreground"
                                Value="#90E53935" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex"
                                Value="100" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Presenter"
                                Property="UserControl.Foreground"
                                Value="#E53935" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Root"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource TransparentWheat}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I  already tried to substitute `UserControl` for the exact name of the user control, which also appears to not work.

Comment: TargetName must refer to an existing name in the so called `NameScope` of the ControlTemplate itself. I.E an element declared in your template. 
That UserControl is not part of the template, but only added to the visual tree when that template is applied.
You need different mechanics for controlling its background color.
If you set that background to the Grid `Root` it would at least be inherited to the ContentPresenter content through dependency property system.

Comment: Maybe this is a pointer (not identical but similar)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946955/setter-for-elements-inside-contentpresenter

Comment: My problem is regarding the foreground color, which has no corresponding property for the Grid Control.

Comment: The link you provided is indeed a satisfying solution for my problem, it feels quite hacky but if it works, it works.

Comment: Normally the TabItem.Foreground does not apply to the content elements  of the TabControl. You must be doing something wrong.